# listview with kopokami in each row, how to handle a click on them?

Tags: java, android, mobile

There is a list of listview, in each row is a button that, when clicked on it to display in this row has one button (delete).
I'm still new to android. Tell me how to organize such a behavior, not quite sure how to determine when you click on the button to which line they belong.

Comment: Make your question a little more specific and clear.

Comment: I'm not sure what 'kopokami' is supposed to mean... Has this question been auto-translated from another language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that you have a delete button in every list row in the listview. I assume that you have a custom layout for the row then. If you have implemented this custom layout in a custom list adapter you have the getView() method in the adapter where you inflate the layout into the row. There you can edit the id of the button like this:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            }
            Button b = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            // here the id
            b.setId(position);
            return v;
    }
```

When you get the onclick somewhere in your app you can access the source of the event and get the id.

I don't know if this is a good way to implement it and if it meets your needs but it is a simple solution.

Comment: @jushlwest If this answered your question, don't forget to mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the tick icon on the left.